# Multistage pipeline not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a relatively simple YAML pipeline below for doing the following.

- Restore any dependencies
- Build any projects
- Run any tests
- Publish the results

This is split across multiple stages that have multiple jobs.

[image]

The issue is that the jobs do not seem to be aware of the previous jobs. This is making the steps take longer to complete and / or have unexpected results. For example the publish artifacts does not publish anything as it has no artifacts from the previous jobs to publish.

How do I make the stages and jobs are of previous actions so that the pipeline works as expected?

```
trigger:
 - master

stages:
- stage: RestoreDependancies
  jobs:
  - job: RestoreNuGetPackages
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
      - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
        displayName: 'Install NuGet'
        inputs:
          versionSpec: 
          checkLatest: true

      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        displayName: 'Restore NuGet'
        inputs:
          command: 'restore'
          restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
          feedsToUse: 'select'

- stage: Build
  dependsOn: RestoreDependancies
  jobs: 
  - job: BuildVisualStudioProjects
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Build Projects'
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration "Release"'

- stage: Test
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs: 
  - job: TestVisualStudioProjects
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Run all Unit Tests'
      inputs:
        command: 'test'
        projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration "Release" --collect "Code coverage"'

- stage: Publish
  dependsOn:
  - Build
  - Test
  jobs:
  - job: PublishTestResults
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
      inputs:
        testResultsFormat: 'XUnit'
        testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
        failTaskOnFailedTests: true
        buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  - job: PublishArtifacts
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Artifacts'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
        Contents: '**\bin\**' # Contents: '**\bin\Release\**'
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifacts'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stages not intended to Restore/Build/Test/Publish Artifacts, all those steps should be in one stage with one job and multiple steps.

Each stage it's a new fresh agent and the agent download again the code, this is the reason why it takes a lot of time and has no artifacts to publish, each stage not know the other stages (by default).

So when you want a new stage? for running functional test or deploy your app, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I appreciate it. You said `"each stage not know the other stages (by default)"`. How would I make each stage aware of the previous one. For example, if I want to run functional tests or deploy my app, how do I get the results from the previous stage to do that?

Comment: Hi @Dan, for this you need to publish the artifacts in the end of the build stage with Publish Pipeline Artifact task, and in the second stage download the filed with Download Pipeline Artifact task.